# How to fetch data from tables by using sql

Tags: sql, oracle10g

**Table_1**

```
Id | name         
1  | abc             
2  | xyz
```

**Table_2**

```
Id | name
3  | sgha
5  | dshhb
```

I want to get all  data from **table 1** and i want data of only `Id` in **table 2**..

**Expected output**

```
Id | name
1  | abc
2  | xyz
3  | null
5  | null
```

Comment: simply using joins

Comment: Can you post the  query

Comment: Tag spamming! And why asking for "Oracle" and tag with any other DB system?

Comment: can u post sample data with ur output

Comment: Actually this question was ask in java develpoer interview .... i used left ofter join i interviewer send u are doi g wrong

Comment: I want to know wat is the right ans ...since m not strong in database

Comment: @GauravSingh I further edited the intended output for the question... please check if this you want ..

Comment: Could be a full outer join or a union - hard to say without expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(Table_1.id, Table_2.id) AS id, Table_1.name
from Table_1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2
ON Table_1.id = Table2.id
```

Maybe this will solve your problem..

**COALESCE** Function work here

**Please do not downvote the question..**

Comment: Yaa...so by using coalesce only one colume will be disply with  data of both the table(t1.id and t2.id)

Answer (score 0):

It's simply `JOINS` like this:

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.name, T2.id 
FROM table1 T1 JOIN table2 T2 
ON --T1.ID=T2.ID
```

if the ID is the same for stablish the relationship--`

IN THE CASE YOU DON'T WANT TO USE `JOINS` you can do this:

```
SELECT id,name FROM table1
UNION
SELECT id,name FROM table2 --if you want the two columns
```

Comment: I dont to compare table1.id=table2.id

Comment: Id matches or not still all details should be display

Comment: And i wat about  table 2  id...data of that should also be shown...without using equilty opertor

Comment: That query show table2 id too, shows all data of table1 and id of table 2, i don't understand what is your question.

Comment: this is the required output what the user wants

Comment: @DouglasFigueroa In your answer the second query will not work as the union and union all operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: ON--t1.id=t2.id  can u expln  how this works.

Comment: It's for stablish the relationship for the `JOIN's` into the two tables involved, is required.

Comment: So from  your first query  what would be output  from table1 and table 2   does  its like  id|name|id

Answer (score 0):

Well first, you will have a problem selecting 2 fields in 2 tables with the same name, however, you can alias field the same field names (Id).

```
Select 
Id = Table_1.Id, 
Name = Table_1.Name,
Id2 = Table_2.Id

From Table_1
Inner Join Table_2 On Table_1.Id = Table_2.Id
```

Comment: If u dont want mind can you expln me what is diffn betwen inner join and equi join

Comment: And what if id.table1 doesnt match with id.table2

Comment: This is not a correct solution

Comment: I want to get all data even id matches or not

Comment: then try using cross joins ... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: OUTER JOIN returns all the rows from the first table, even if there are no matches in the second table. OUTER JOIN returns all the rows from the second table, even if there are no matches in the first table.. INNER JOIN requires there is at least a match in comparing the two tables.